# Amateur Hour: Python Dictionary Structuring

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm still in the beginning stages of learning programming and Python, but I'm struggling with how to best use a dictionary or if I even should. Currently, I'd like to have a "table" in the format such that:

```
   user   attr         loc
   ----   ----         ----
    1     red,green    here
    2     blue         there
    3     yellow       here, there
   ...    ...          ...
    n     black        nowhere
```

For the purposes of what I'm trying to do, I'd like to be able to call 'user = 1' with the 'attr' column (or sometimes 'loc') returned back as a list like ['red', 'green'].

My question is this: If the data I'm interested in is more than one column, is treating it as a dataframe the only (or best?) way to retrieve the information off a given row? It seems like dictionaries will be limited to just two columns with the key/value pairings.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You can also consider creating an object, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of a dictionary element can be anything.  So if you want multiple things embed another dictionary.

```
'''
   user   attr         loc
   ----   ----         ----
    1     red,green    here
    2     blue         there
    3     yellow       here, there
   ...    ...          ...
    n     black        nowhere
'''

d = { 
    1: {'attr':('red','green'), 'loc':'here'},
    2: {'attr':('blue'), 'loc':'there'},

    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print d
    print d[1]['loc']
    pass
```

output:

```
{1: {'loc': 'here', 'attr': ('red', 'green')}, 2: {'loc': 'there', 'attr': 'blue'}}
here
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to have a "table" in the format such that...

May I suggest pandas then:

```
import pandas as pd
d = { 
    1: {'attr':('red','green'), '_loc':'here'},
    2: {'attr':('blue'), '_loc':'there'},
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.index.name = 'user'
print(df)
              attr   _loc
user                     
1     (red, green)   here
2             blue  there
```

Note that I named the column `_loc` to avoid confusion with the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) property.

For your purposes this mainly gets you a prettier-looking data structure that is also easier and more flexible to query I would argue:

```
print(df.loc[1, 'attr'])  # user 1 attrs
('red', 'green')

print(df.loc[1, '_loc'])  # user 1 attrs
here

print(df.loc[1])  # user 1 all records
attr    (red, green)
_loc            here
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,you can implement a nested dictionary.

```
user[1]['attr']
>>>['red','green']
user[1]['loc']
>>>'here'
```